# What is "create" in mongo dump files?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I am trying to restore a mngo db from dump. Here is `sessions.metadata.json` snippet:

```
{
  "options": {
    "create": "sessions",
    "flags": 1
  },
  "indexes": [
    {
      "v": 1,
      "name": "_id_",
      "key": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "ns": "myPrefix.sessions"
    },
    {
      "v": 1,
      "name": "expires_1",
      "key": {
        "expires": 1
      },
      "ns": "myPrefix.sessions",
      "expireAfterSeconds": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The source mongo db version is `2.4` target mongo is `3.6`. And I get error:

```
Failed: myPrefix.sessions: error creating collection myPrefix.sessions: error running create command: Parsed command object contains duplicate top level key: create
```

As I spot other `metadata.json` files which restored without errors do not contain `options` section. Why it is needed? Can I safely remove `options` section from my `sessions.metadata.json`?

Comment: [It might be a known issue in mongo](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22958?focusedCommentId=1208466&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1208466). Does this help?

Comment: No it is about collection items, while I got error during collection create not during items inserting phase.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but I was facing exactly the same issue (mongo 2.4 to mongo 3.6 dump) and the solution was to create the database and the collection manually, before doing mongorestore.
This probably jumps the create part of the statement and so avoids what I think is an import bug between different versions of mongodump/restore.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue too with a MongoDB 3.4 server:

```
2019-12-18T09:19:14.881+0100  reading metadata for my_db.posts from dump/my_db/posts.metadata.json
2019-12-18T09:19:14.882+0100  creating collection my_db.posts using options from metadata
2019-12-18T09:19:14.883+0100  Failed: my_db.posts: error creating collection my_db.posts: error running create command: Parsed command object contains duplicate top level key: create
```

Looking at the content of the `dump/my_db/posts.metadata.json` file, I saw that:

```
{ "options" : { "create" : "posts" }, "indexes" : [ { "v" : 1, "name" : "_id_", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "my_db.posts" } ] }
```

I also checked another collection which worked and it wasn't including this `options` attribute.

Removing it and re-running `mongorestore` fixed the issue. I had few more files where I had to delete this `options` attribue, and the restore finishes normally then.